# Is there a word for one who enjoys to eat for the sake of eating (a food hedonist)?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, american-english, synonyms

Does such a word exist? I don't mean to excess (IE, a glutton), but rather one who eats because he enjoys eating. Essentially, I'm looking for a word that's synonymous with "a food hedonist", or "a hedonistic eater." A word would be ideal, but a term would suffice as well :).

I love to eat!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Words that describe food and eating](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143323/words-that-describe-food-and-eating)

Comment: The question referred to has been closed because it was deemed 'too broad.' If one feels my question is a "possible duplicate," bring the issue up with the moderators rather than sullying my post with unfounded speculations. Thank you.

Comment: The site works by self-regulation in the first instance. There _is_ already an answer here, that would appear by searching for [person fond of food](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132223/gourmand-and-gourmet/132231#132231). However, I think Erik's 'epicure' and 'gastrowhatsits' are worth keeping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Foodie" is a more informal term.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foodie): "A foodie is a gourmet, or a person who has an ardent or refined interest in food and alcoholic beverages. A foodie seeks new food experiences as a hobby rather than simply eating out of convenience or hunger."

Comment: When you're quoting a text in order to support your answer, it can be useful to other readers to know where it comes from.  :-)

Comment: This is the best term here.

Comment: "Foodie" is a term which makes me cringe almost as much as this... http://www.4music.com/shows/last-fan-standing

Comment: A foodie is someone who not only enjoys eating, but knows a lot about food. Like all nerds who get heavily into what they enjoy and learn more than most, they are food nerds. It's more accurate than epicure, which is not specific to food.

Comment: A _gastronome_ would be a less recent synonym for a foodie.

Answer (score 13):

*Gourmand, gourmet* and *epicure* appear to match what you're after, as perhaps does *food connoisseur*.

Comment: YES! Though, I'm confused, since Merriam alternatively defines it as "a person who eats and drinks too much," while also listing "glutton" as a near antonym. That makes no sense. The primary definition is spot on, however.

Comment: I can't disagree with you about Merriam-Webster's inconsistent treatment of *gourmand* vs. *glutton*. BTW, I've just recalled another couple of terms, *gastronome* and *gastronomist*.

Comment: @user2384224 see also: epicurean

Comment: I thought a gastronome was something bagpipe players used to keep time.

Comment: @Edwin - The other kind of gastronome is a sort of snail-eating troll.

Comment: The gastronomes of Zurich: Swiss trolls.

Comment: @Edwin - A sort of jellytroll...?

Comment: And don’t forget: [in the boudoir, the gourmand metamorphoses into the voluptuary](http://www.decipheringthesimpsons.com/index.php?p1=vocab&p2=gourmand)!

Comment: @Edwin: Soviet food shops were called "Gastronom". I don't think an epicure would agree.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from "**gourmand**," consider "[**bon vivant**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_vivant)," "**food epicurean**," and "**hearty eater**."

> [**bon vivant**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bon%20vivant): (*from French*) a person who enjoys going out with friends and eating good food and drinking good wine.

to be compared with:

> [**hedonist**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hedonist): a person whose life is devoted to the pursuit of pleasure and self-gratification.

And

> [**bon viveur**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bon%20viveur): a person who lives high and well; man-about-town.

However, "gourmet" and "gastronome" don't necessarily imply a hedonistic behavior to my French ear, but rather some sophisticated knowledge about high quality (often expensive) food and wines, coupled with the enjoyment of choosing, eating and drinking them.

Comment: I am learning French and I agree on your observations.  Yet we are on ELU and you seem to have a lot of French answers.  I enjoy the French answers because it allows me to learn but it sure gets into the grey area of what English is or isn't.

Comment: I’m sure you know this, but just for the internet record, English has a pretty strong French influence, thanks to them [taking us over in 1066](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/1422173/Old-Europe-gloats-as-it-wins-the-first-round.html). There are quite a few French phrases that have been adopted into English when we don’t have a term for them — *bon vivant* is one, *joie de vivre* is another. (And if it sounds like the French have more phrases for being happy than we do, I assure you that’s entirely coincidental. Oh look, it’s raining again.)

Answer (score 3):

A **gourmand** is someone who loves to eat "food for food's sake."

This is in contrast to a **gourmet,** whose interest is in "fine" food.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off the precise word-topic would be a *trencherman* which best describes a person who has a hearty appetite and has no difficulty in eating all that is set before him.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trencherman)

> a person who has a hearty appetite; a heavy eater

Comment: Answers here should have a source and a link, which I added for you.   (Standards are higher now than when this question and most of its answers were posted.)  The only place I have seen this word used is in the [Gideon of Scotland Yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gideon_of_Scotland_Yard) books -- a great series.  Commander Gideon was frequently described as a trencherman.

Comment: Many thanks to ab2 for informing us of a "source and a link" to support my offering of "trencherman". I am new to this marvelous site and continue to learn about its rules of engagement.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia such a person could be described as "good on the fang".

Answer (score 0):

How about a ***Mealophile***, or a ***Morselist***?

What about ***Gastronomical***  (or just ***Gastro***?)

Answer (score -1):

I think the most common word for this - food hedonist - is **pig**.

It is highly negative to call someone a pig so usually it would be used to describe someone not present or used to describe yourself.

> Usage:
>
> I basically like any kind of candy.  I can eat all night.  I am such a
>   pig.
>
> We can't buy any snacks that mom likes.  She's such a pig, she will
>   eat them before we get a chance.

_

---

_

Also a more clinical word with the exact meaning is **Sitomania**.

> - an obsession with food
> - An abnormal craving for food

Answer (score -1):

***Epicure***

> A person who takes particular pleasure in fine food and drink.
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/epicure)

Answer (score -1):

Sybarite / Sybaritic expresses the enjoyment of fine food and drink.

> a person who is self-indulgent in their fondness for sensuous luxury.

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sybarite&oq=sybarite&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1832j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)