# Epicure, gourmet distinction

Tags: meaning

Anticipating a delicious meal shortly, we have found ourselves in rival camps of *gourmets* and *epicures*.  My OED searching suggests these are, essentially, the same.  Do you agree ?

OED entry for *gourmet*:

> A connoisseur of good food; a person with a discerning palate.

OED entry for *epicure*:

> A person who takes particular pleasure in fine food and drink.

Comment: Simple yes/no questions lacking any elaboration are going to generate low-quality answers.  They also tend to be closed either as Primarily Opinion Based or Off-topic Proofreading questions.  So you might want to work on that.  They are also prone to closure as General Reference / Show Us Your Research — which you have not done. You merely allude to it; you do not show what you found.

Comment: OED goumet: A connoisseur of good food; a person with a discerning palate.

Comment: OED epicure: A person who takes particular pleasure in fine food and drink:

Comment: @tchrist  I gave my research - an authoratative, respected source.  I am inviting you to share your language and usage.

Comment: Please edit your research into your question; comments are ephemera.  Also, "inviting people to share" is provoking discussions, not answers.

Comment: The question is - Do you consider the two words to be synonyms.  The research - OED - is in front of you.

Comment: related: [Is there a word for one who enjoys to eat for the sake of eating (a food hedonist)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169482/is-there-a-word-for-one-who-enjoys-to-eat-for-the-sake-of-eating-a-food-hedonis)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, clearly related.  The question is simply whether, in modern English, an epicurean and a gourmet are the same thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done as requested.  For the life of me I don't understand why so much attention is spent correcting a perfectly simple question.  Do you have an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are similar enough to be considered synonyms, but they are not exactly the same.

Gourmet refers to food and drink exclusively. In contrast, epicure hints at sensual pleasures in addition to food and drink, with both the OED and Merriam-Webster focusing the meaning of the word as being "especially" related to food and drink -- implying there's more beyond food and drink.

Comment: Can you give citations to support this please ?

Comment: @Dan - added a reference