# What is a word for someone who loves eating?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

(I'm looking specifically for 'Bilbo Baggins' in The Hobbit)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Where to start?! There are so many. You should provide more context rather than just a word to describe Bilbo, who is no different from any other hobbit when it comes to food.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Is there a word for one who enjoys to eat for the sake of eating ...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169482/is-there-a-word-for-one-who-enjoys-to-eat-for-the-sake-of-eating-a-food-hedonis/169560#169560), but unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try *gourmand*

A gourmand is someone who takes pleasure in eating and drinking, often to excess

Comment: Could you provide a link to an online dictionary? Answers without this are often deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Sandra Boynton describes three varieties:

[image: Gourmet, gourmand, gourmoo]

Comment: As always, decent humour trumps downvoteworthiness.

Answer (score 0):

A **greedy**, **gravalicious** or **gluttonous** little Hobbit.

I like words with G when describing people who love to eat :)